# How to redraw the keyboard of a UITExtview when i change return key type when already displayed

Tags: ios, keyboard, refresh, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

In a UitTextview, i want the keyboard return key to operate like a newline key when user is typing, and i want the same key to turn to a Done key after few seconds of inactivity and dismiss the keyboard when touched instead of inserting a newline

I've modified the textview delegates to do the newline versus dismiss keyboard mechanism and to switch the keyboard return key from UIReturnKeyDefault to UIReturnKeyDone and the newline versus dismiss mechanism works great. the only problem i have is that when i change the return key type to self.TextView.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone; the keyboard is not refresh/redrawn and i cannot see the done key. I've tried doing a setNeedsDisplay on the UITextView and on my main view, but nothing happen. The keyboard return key does not change . When the keyboard is dismissed and then reappear when user reenter the textview then the done key is here.

What should i do to have the done key being redrawn while keyboard is active and display ?

Here is the uitextview delegates i used:

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    text_newline_mode=YES;
    self.TextView.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDefault;
}

- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)txtView
{
    text_newline_mode=YES;
    self.TextView.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDefault;
    if (keyboard_timer)
        [keyboard_timer invalidate];  // cancel previous timer when user continue typing 
        keyboard_timer =    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(enableKeyboardDoneKey:)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:NO];

}
-(void)enableKeyboardDoneKey:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    text_newline_mode=NO;
    keyboard_timer = nil;
    self.TextView.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    [self.TextView setNeedsDisplay]; // this does not refresh the keyboard
    [self.view setNeedsDisplay]; //this does not help neither

}
- (BOOL)textViewShouldEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    if (text_newline_mode==YES)
    {
        self.TextView.text = [self.TextView.text stringByAppendingString:@"\n"];
    return NO;
    }
    else return YES;
}
- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)txtView
{
     self.feedbackTextView.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDefault;
     text_newline_mode=YES;
}
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {

    if(([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) && (text_newline_mode==NO))
    {
        [textView resignFirstResponder];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

I looked everywhere but were not able to find any information on how to refresh the keyboard keys while keyboard is displayed.
Any ideas ?
thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

In my view, we can't change the `returnKeyType` once the keyboard is displayed. I have other alternate. Once check this.

Store the time when a key is entered initially, then compare it with the time whenever the new key is entered. Then, based upon your time delay, check your condition in

```
static NSDate *tempDate = [NSDate date];


- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
    //Store the initial time

    NSDate *dateEntered = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval interval = [dateEntered timeIntervalSinceDate:tempDate];

    if (interval > 10.0f) //10.0 is your buffer time, after which you want to dismiss the keyboard
    {

        if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
            [textView resignFirstResponder];
            return NO;
        }

    }

    tempDate = dateEntered;

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: that was i was doing with the NStimer , but then the user does not know after how many seconds it will dismiss that's why i wanted to change the return key to done, that way he knows, but as you said maybe it's not possible to refresh the keyboard other than dismissing and recalling it. do you have any idea if we can change the way the keyboard is displayed originally (slide from bottom) to no slide/animation, maybe that i can change key, dismiss, recall keyboard and user will only see the return key change and no slide out and slide in animation . any clue ?